# Truncated string at mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, utf-8, character-encoding

I have spent the entire day trying to figure this out, I hope you can help

**PROBLEM:** inserting "Cosío" into mysql database

what happens is that the string gets cut at the accent so it only inserts "Cos"

if I do the following:`echo mb_detect_encoding($_POS['name'], "auto");` it show UTF-8

Reading some post here and there i followed some of the advice and did the following

```
mysql database : collation = utf8_general_ci
mysql table: collation = utf8_general_ci
mysql field: collation = utf8_general_ci
```

I am using codeigniter framework and my database conection is a follows:

```
  $active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'codeigniter',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => false,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

on apache config i also added `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`

also declared html tag `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

and i have read and read several SO post but with no success.
What am I missing?

UPDATE:
I am getting closer to the problem, before doing the insert query i am sanitizing all post variables like so.

```
$ready_for_insert = ucwords(strtolower(filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
```

if i remove filter sanitize string, everything works good. I do this to clean the string of any tags or malicius input i dont know if I should remove it.

Comment: How about your DB connection?

Comment: You set the character set of your columns as well?

Comment: since i am using codeigniter my db conection char_set is set to utf8 as you can see on the code above.  I also added $DB->simple_query('SET NAMES \'utf8\''); on DB class but still it truncates

Comment: Yes, database, table, and columns

Comment: Search for "Truncation" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full Unicodes are not supported by MySQL's utf-8 encoding.

In your example `Cosío`, `í` is not supported and properly encoded before saving into the database. So the characters after that unicode are being stripped off by MySQL. Only `Cos` will be saved in the database.

If you want to support full unicodes, you have to switch the encoding to `utf8mb4`

This could be done as below.

> ## For each database:
>
> ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
>
> ## For each table:
>
> ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
>
> ## For each column:
>
> ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
>
> (Don’t blindly copy-paste this! The exact statement depends on the column type, maximum length, and other properties. The above line is just an example for a VARCHAR column.)

Please refer [this link](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) for more info